# Is filter(x => !!x) the same as filter(x => !!x && x)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter, rxjs

Is `filter(x => !!x)` the same as `filter(x => !!x && x)`? In both cases the method returns the same thing but I want to know the theories of the answer.

Comment: TLDR: `!!x` will filter falsy values (such as undefined, null, 0, ...) while `!!x && x` add an additional check where `x` needs to be also evaluated to `true`

Comment: Where did you find this code in the first place? `!!x && x` makes no sense.

Comment: "*wants to know the theories of the answer*" - what is your current theory about why they are the same? Please explain your current thinking

Comment: This implies `!!!x != !x` which is suspect.

Comment: "In both cases the method returns the same thing" — If by "method" you mean your callback function then you're wrong. If you mean the `filter` function, then we don't know what that function is so can't tell.

Comment: @jcalz I had removed the [tag:rxjs] tag because I thought [tag:filter] would be enough to identify this as a boolean predicate, but OP is referring to https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter if you need to know. Edit: I've added it back.

Comment: `!!x` - double negation, to produce a `boolean`. So without it you use implicit `boolean` conversion, and with `!!` you use explicit `boolean` conversion. That's the difference.

Comment: I don't know anything about rxjs's filter... does it check for `true` or for *truthy* results?  If it's the former then there is a difference, if it's the latter then there is no difference.  Essentially the difference depends on `filter()`, so the question should explain exactly what that is doing

Comment: @jcalz: RxJS' [`filter`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/72bc92191ab959e27a969dc4476e14d95416573f/src/internal/operators/filter.ts#L72) uses short-circuit evaluation to check the expression. So it checks for truthiness, not `true`. I'd say for the specific use case of RxJS `filter` operator, there is _no_ difference between the expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the same ,in the `filter` method, the return value will be regarded as Boolean

`!!x` === `Boolean(!!x)` === `Boolean(x)`

`!!x && x` === `Boolean(!!x && x)` === `Boolean(x) && Boolean(x)` === `Boolean(x)`

Hahaha, so it's equivalent, that's what I think

---

But in a assignment expression in the following code

```js
const a = !!x && x
const b = !!x
```

The results of these two expressions are different

For `&&` operator, `exp1 && exp2`, if exp1 returns false, the exp2 will not execute, but when exp1 returns true, the exp2 will still execute.

So in assignment expressions

- `!!x` will always return `true || false`,so to speak `Boolean`
- `!!x` is false

  - `!!x` will always equals `!!x && x`
- `!!x` is true

  - `!!x` equals `!!x && x` when `x` is a `Boolean`
  - In other cases, the two are not equivalent

Comment: `!!x && x === Boolean(x) && Boolean(x)` <- that's not valid. Given `x = 5` the former evaluates to `5`, the latter evaluates to `true`.

Comment: But in the `filter` method, the return value will be regarded as Boolean, so `Boolean(5)` and `Boolean(true)` is same

Comment: In assignment expression, It's not correct,I need to edit my answer to avoid any potential misinterpretation.

Comment: The OP is not asking about assignment, only about the filter predicate.  You should remove everything after *But in a assignment expression...*.

Answer (score 0):

Let's run some tests and see what different values output for each of those. This will show you what happens for each value

```js
const values = [-1, 0, 1, 2, {a:'foo'}, null, undefined, true, false, 'true', 'false', 'foo'];

let htmlStr = '';
values.forEach(x => {
  htmlStr += `
  <tr>
    <td>${JSON.stringify(x, null, 0)}</td>
    <td><code>${JSON.stringify(!!x, null, 0)}</code></td>
    <td><code>${JSON.stringify((!!x && x), null, 0)}</code></td>
  </tr>`;
});

document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = htmlStr;
```

```css
table, th, td {border:1px solid #DDD; border-collapse:collapse;}
td, th {padding: .25rem;}
code{color: #b71313;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th><code>!!x</code></th>
      <th><code>!!x && x</code></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

The purpose of a `filter` function is to determine what should or should not be included in the results, thus everything should return a `boolean`.  The results here show that the `!!x` method always returns a boolean, so for the absolute basics this works best.

However, keep in mind that **just because it's a boolean doesn't necessarily mean that what it's converting into a boolean makes sense in your application!**  For example: Are you sure you want the string `"false"` to be converted into `true`?

To summarize: `!!x` will convert things to booleans every time, but you need to make sure what is being converted makes sense for your use case.  It's not a catch-all since there are so many ways this could go wrong.

Comment: What conclusion do you draw from the test results?

Comment: Since a `filter` function usually wants a boolean back to determine if the item should be included in the filter results or not, it appears that `!!x` is always returning a boolean.  So that seems to make the most sense as long as the conversions it is doing make sense in your app.  Do you always want `-1` to evaluate to `true` for example (if that can even happen in your app)

Comment: This answer is not really useful without an explanation

Comment: Ok, explanation added

Answer (score -1):

**`!!x` is not equal to `!!x && x`**

---

**But Why does it return the same thing when used in filter?**

first to understand how variables are evaluated during a conditional statement, refer:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

for a lot of use case, in order to filter only truthy value, filter method can simply be written as follow:
`filter(x => x)`

while falsy filter can be written as:
`filter(x => !x)`

now, given some sample variable

```js
const x = "A"

const notX     = !x        // false  (!"A")
const notNotX  = !!x       // true   (!!"A")/(!notX)

const whatIsThis = (notNotX && x) // "A" || can be read as (true && "A")

// in any other context, it is evaluated as original value of x, in this case: "A"
console.log(whatIsThis) 
// in the context of boolean, it is evaluated as truthy 
if(whatIsThis) console.log(true)

console.log(whatIsThis === notNotX)  // false, whatIsThis is not equal to notNotX
```

anytime that `x` itself would be evaluated as **truthy**,
`!!x` will returns `true`

another other way to understand why filter return same result, try reading the statement as

- `!!x` is `true`
- `!!x && x` is  `true && "truthy"`

Comment: You claim that `filter(x => !!x)` is not the same as `filter(x => !!x && x)`, but can you give any example input value to filter where they produce different outputs?

Comment: @Bergi i'm assuming u didnt read the whole thing? my point was that `!!x && x` and  `!!x` will returns different value when placed in any other context other than boolean

Comment: That is not what the answer said before your edit though. Thanks for the update!